# python - slice nested lists using nested list of index

Tags: python, list, slice

I have a nested list

```
import numpy as np
mylist = np.array([[12, 11, 14, 15, 66],
                   [3, 5, 6],
                   [13, 4, 7, 33, 98]])
myindex = [[0, 2, 3],
           [2],
           [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

How can I slice `mylist` using `myindex`?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use zip, and a list comprehension for this.

```
slices = []
for ix, l in zip(myindex, mylist): 
    slices.append([l[i] for i in ix])
```

Output

```
[[12, 14, 15], [6], [4, 7, 33, 98]]
```